# How to run code when Stateless widget is created

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a screen made using Stateless Widget.
I want to run some code when the screen is loaded or when the Stateless widget is created.

In android we could do this in onCreate() method.
i.e. is there some equivalent of onCreate() in flutter.

Comment: You can use a [StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) instead and use the `initState` method, if you are modifying the state of the widget.

Comment: Is this the only way. Because I won't be modifying any state of the widget.

Comment: Could you specify what you are trying to do `onCreate`?

Comment: I want to set alarm by alarm manager when the application starts.

Comment: You can simply include it in your main method: `void main() => {startAlarm(); runApp(MyApp());}`

Comment: umm, depends on what you mean by `created`.. why not just use the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology for this is "mount". So you want to run the code when the widget is mounted. In Flutter, all widgets have a `mounted` property and it turns true when the `buildContext` is assigned to a widget.

But I don't think you can do something to workaround with that property.

`bool get mounted => _element != null;`

[relevant line](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L963)

I think what you can do is turn your widget into Stateful widget and use `initState()`